# FTPS using java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, weblogic, ftps

My requirement is: transfer files to another server using secure FTP with java
I used org.apache.commons.net for SFTP client but later realized windows doesn't have native SFTP support.
So opted FTPS with same apache jar.
Now using IIS manager on server I created a self-signed certificate which I converted from .pfx to .jks using : [oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/steps-to-create-a-jks-keystore-from-pfx-file)

I used both approaches before java 6 and after java 6 provided in the blog, for two different certificates.

certificates were successfully imported but now getting below error:

<6 Sep, 2018 8:29:34 PM IST>      <> <> <> <1536245974206>  <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group for Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBuffer[]) called: result=Status = OK **HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING**

bytesConsumed = 741 bytesProduced = 687.>

<6 Sep, 2018 8:29:34 PM IST>      <> <> <> <1536245974206>

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: **peer not authenticated**
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.VirtualConnection.initSSLAttributes(VirtualConnection.java:176)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.VirtualConnection.init(VirtualConnection.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.initFromRequestParser(ServletRequestImpl.java:269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.MuxableSocketHTTP.dispatch(MuxableSocketHTTP.java:324)
    at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.dispatch(JSSEFilterImpl.java:202)
    at weblogic.socket.NTSocketMuxer.processSockets(NTSocketMuxer.java:105)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)

I have a few questions along with above problem:

1. Why self signed certificate created using IIS doesn't require a password when exported without private key.
2. What are these formats .pfx, .pem, .jks (I have slight idea but require more info).
3. When used second approach provided in above link. It removed my older entry from keystore.
   `keytool -list -v -keystore identity.jks -storepass keystorepass
   Your keystore contains 1 entry
   where as previously It contained 2 entries.`
4. What is difference between require ssl connection and allow ssl connection in IIS manager SSl settings.

Thanks

Comment: I received one clarification that instead of importing third party ssl certificate to my java key store it should be added to trust store (cacerts). I used openssl to convert .pfx to .cer using:

Comment: command: <code>openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.cer -nodes </code> Then manually removed private key entry from file using text editor and then imported this cert file to cacerts available at: ..\jre\lib\security using :<code>keytool -import -alias aliasname -file certificate.cer -keystore path_to\cacerts -storepass changeit<\code>but still getting same issue handshake not happening. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please share your code here.